# Duplicates data after joining trigger table with other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, duplicates, inner-join

I want to fetch the BEFORE and AFTER data from TableProduct whenever there is an update. So I created a Before and After trigger queries in which the respected values from the trigger is stored in separate tables titled TableProduct_Before and TableProduct_After.

My challenge is I always get duplicates result whenever I try to INNER  JOIN the three tables.

I have tried the DISTINCT and ORDER BY ID command but still the same challenge.

I made enquiry I was told I can't join trigger table values because it doesn't have a foreign key, I tried adding a foreign key but it didn't work saying foreign key already exists in TableProduct.

Please, I will appreciate any help thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding how triggers work.  You can use either a before or after trigger.

The key is using `new` and `old`.  Inside the body of the trigger, you have both the old and new values.  In pseudocode, this looks like:

```
insert into archive (pk, old_value, new_value)
    values (new.pk, old.value, new.value);
```

Comment: I'm fine with the use of trigger, I was able to retrieve the information I wanted. My challenge is with the duplicates data that I got when trying to join the tables together using INNER JOIN. I'm trying to get rid of the duplicate values when I join the trigger table values and the original table values together.

Answer (score 0):

Both OLD and NEW data is available in both before and after trigger.

The difference is - BEFORE trigger fixes the attempt to update whereas AFTER fixes successful attempt result. I.e. BEFORE is executed anycase (but its changes may be rollbacked!), rather than AFTER.

See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd19c611c7e2fbef88b2133dcaa61dfa

PS. Recent MySQL versions allows triggers chains - a lot of triggers on the same event fired one-by-one. So check that your saving trigger is the most last in this chain.

Comment: I'm fine with the use of trigger, I was able to retrieve the information I wanted. My challenge is with the duplicates data that I received when trying to join the tables together using INNER JOIN. I'm trying to get rid of the duplicate values when I join the trigger table values and the original table values together.

Comment: @AdolijeEmmanuel If you want to get rid of the duplicate values then use only one of the triggers, not both - BEFORE if you want to save any attempt, including unsuccessful, AFTER if you need to save only successful attempts.